# Why is this question not closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590801/creating-autorun-cd-menu-without-additional-files) as off-topic and downvoted it.

After a while I came back to it (my flag is not resolved yet) and found that another user has upvoted it.

So I'm wondering is this on topic and am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: It's not "off-topic" as much as it's "too broad". I've close-voted it as such.

Comment: It's off-topic.  Nor could it be useful, in general.  I don't know of anyone stu... incompetent enough to have autorun enabled.  Not for a decade have I seen it enabled.

Comment: Creating an autorun disc used to be a programmer's job.  Luckily it is no longer relevant and the question has no happy answer when it is so thoroughly unresearched like this.  Sympathy upvoting is not uncommon.

Comment: @Cerbrus too broad fits too but "Which program can do something like that?" is a blatant software recommendation so that reason fits as well

Comment: Absolutely right, @gnat.

Comment: In future, discussing the closure of posts is something the [SO Close Vote Review room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) excels at (but do check out their [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq)).

Comment: @MartijnPieters understood thanks I did not know about this.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are *way* more questions that need to be closed than can be handled by the people who actively review close votes (requires reputation >= 3k, but the person has to actually spend the time to do so; most don't). The close-vote review-queue typically hovers around 10,000 questions. A large portion of those leave the queue without being closed (close-votes/flags age away, someone edits the question from within the queue, enough people say leave it open, etc.). Unfortunately, you will probably find that a large portion of the questions you flag for closure don't get closed.

Comment: Meta Effect in 3... Oh, I'm too late.

Comment: Uhh, you can apply this question to literally any "rule" on SE.  There is no consistency.  Don't get me started on inconsistency in deleting comments.

Comment: @Kik well said.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Questions get closed when users with enough reputation see them and cast a close vote. This can sometimes take years to happen organically, or, as Martijn mentioned, can happen *very quickly* when brought to the attention of the [Stack Overflow Close Vote Reviewers (SOCVR)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room.

The SOCVR chatroom is a room of normal users like you or me who help close bad or off-topic questions before they can garner lots of answers or bounties, etc. Don't go posting any question you want closed there willy-nilly, though. The room has specific rules which you can read on [its website](https://socvr.org/).

Oh, and the question you linked to is now closed.

Comment: "This can sometimes take years to happen organically" Isn't taking years basically a de facto "keep open" now that close votes age away?

Comment: @jpmc26: Yes, pretty much. Key phrase being *de facto*.

Comment: @jpmc26 Since close votes age away, enough have to be cast within a certain time frame for a question to be closed. A question can have enough votes cast on it within this time period soon within minutes or hours of being asked, or it can have those votes cast on it when someone stumbles upon it years later and sends it to the CV queue with a vote or flag.